# How to use regex to strip [a-z]/[a-z]/ from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say a string is `abc/xyz/IMPORTANT/DATA/@#!%@!%`, and I just want `IMPORTANT/DATA/!%#@%!#%`

I am terrible at regex, and really haven't learned JavaScript API yet

Comment: So you want everything after the last slash?

Comment: I just went back and re-clarified.

Comment: @John Nall: Mmmh. What is the difference between `abc/xyz/` and `IMPORTANT/DATA/!%#@%!#%` ? What about `abc/xyz/IMPORTANT/DATA/` or `abc/MORE/IMPORTANT/DATA/` ? Is it lower and upper case? If not, I think what you want is not possible. You have to be able to distinguish the parts somehow based on their structure.

Comment: @Felix - Good point. I assumed from the title there would be a constant 2 lower case parts though.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Could be, indeed :) Best thing would that the OP clarifies this ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) and [`substring`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp). You don't need regex for this.

You can use the `start` parameter to `indexOf` to search from a given position. If you search after the first `/`, you can find the index of the second `/`.

```
s = "abc/def/ghi/jkl";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('/', s.indexOf('/') + 1) + 1);
document.writeln(s); // "ghi/jkl"
```

Note that this assumes that there will always be at least two `/`. If there isn't, this will keep `s` as it is.

```
s = "abc/xyz";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('/', s.indexOf('/') + 1) + 1);
document.writeln(s); // "abc/xyz"
```

If you want to use regex anyway, it's something like this:

```
s = "abc/def/ghi/jkl";
s = s.replace(/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\//, '');
document.writeln(s); // "ghi/jkl"
```

Again, this assumes that there will always be at least two `/`.

Answer (score 1):

If the text is always like your current example you might be able to simply use `substring` and `indexOf` to cut it starting from the second occurence of the "/".

Otherwise `/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/)/`, or Blair's answer might be a good regexp to use.
Or `/^([^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/)/` if it has to start at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I'm going to look into substring IndexOF, sounds like what I need for good performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
yourstring.replace(/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\/(.+)/g, "$1");
```